# Cannot render "create" and "edit" page as it returns Error 500 in mvc .net framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2017

I'm about to develop an ASP.NET MVC application using AdminLTE template. For the CRUD operation, I used new scaffolded item using create "MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework". The edit and delete works just fine but "create" and "edit" operation did not work out as an error 500 appears after I run these methods.

This is the code for my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using test2.Models;

namespace test2.Views
{
    public class CasesController : Controller
    {
        private eLawDBModel db = new eLawDBModel();

        // GET: Cases
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await db.Cases.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Cases/Details/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Case @case = await db.Cases.FindAsync(id);

            if (@case == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(@case);
        }

        // GET: Cases/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Cases/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "caseID,caseName")] Case @case)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Cases.Add(@case);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(@case);
        }

        // GET: Cases/Edit/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            Case @case = await db.Cases.FindAsync(id);

            if (@case == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(@case);
        }

        // POST: Cases/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "caseID,caseName")] Case @case)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(@case).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(@case);
        }

        // GET: Cases/Delete/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            Case @case = await db.Cases.FindAsync(id);

            if (@case == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(@case);
        }

        // POST: Cases/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Case @case = await db.Cases.FindAsync(id);
            db.Cases.Remove(@case);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the view markup of create operation:

```
@model test2.Models.Case

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Case</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.caseName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.caseName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.caseName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

and this is the view markup for edit operation:

```
@model test2.Models.Case

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Case</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.caseID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.caseName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.caseName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.caseName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

The page shows this error after I run the create operation:

> [ERROR 500]
>   Oops! Something went wrong.
>   There was an error processing your request. Please, try again.
>   If the problem persists, contact support.

The server I am using right now is IIS Windows version 10.0.

Comment: Did you debug the code? There should be some exception thrown from the server code which results in 500 error at the client. You need to debug the code and see what is happening.

Comment: the debug shows `'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132033967643651829): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.` is this the one? @ChetanRanpariya

Answer (score 0):

As you know sometimes [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] making the problem with there browser compatibility, so first remove the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] tag from controller and remove @Html.AntiForgeryToken() from view as well.

Comment: still the same, sir.

Comment: What you need to do the changes in web.config and add the below code. So, you will get the actual error of the application or in code level.

<system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off" />